# Isran keeps trying to kill me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I have gone to Fort Dawnguard to speak to Isran as part of the A New Order quest and when I got there he was fighting with some vampires. I weighed in and helped kill them but also think I hit Isran and now every time I go near there he tries to kill me. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Usually the best solution for these problems is to load a saved game before it happened.

Comment: I don't even make it to Dawnguard and people are trying to kill me. Then everytime I go to Riften I get the same thing. I can't even pay a bounty.

Comment: It happens in the base version of the game, everytime you attack a friendly NPC. You just have to fast travel somewhere else and go back... a couple of times, or more :P

Answer (score 4):

From [A New Order](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/A_New_Order)

Return to Skyrim - I had to run the whole way.
Wait for 24 hours (I went back to Riften), and try again, they were peaceful this time.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem too. I came to Dawnguard and found Isran and his company fighting vampires. I shot at them with my arrow, but I misfired on one shot and it hit one of Isran's company. Because of this, they attacked me and would not stop. I went back to Riften and found I had a bounty on my head because of it. I believe this is the cause of them attacking you, but for good measure I also waited 24 hours, as suggested above, came back and then I could talk to them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a high sneak level 50+. Stun them with a paralyze spell to keep them from moving, then run behind the wall closest to him and he'll talk to you while you're hidden!

Comment: lol does that really work?

Answer (score 0):

Just wait around for them to kill the bad guys then just use the invisibility potion. You can then walk up and talk to him.

Answer (score 0):

You may contract vampirism from killing vampires. If you have vampirism for too long, this can cause people to attack you on sight wether you have a bounty not.

You should be able to see if you have contracted Vampirism in the menus.

Comment: Stage 4 Vampirism no longer causes NPCs to attack you on sight with the Dawnguard addon, only being in Vampire Lord form does this.

Answer (score 0):

just cast the illusion spell harmony, or any spell that calms people. it'll basically reset their reactions to you, unless of course its  naturally aggressive npc