# Why can't I start the quest without the Dawnguard leader attacking me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I recently bought the legendary edition of Skyrim. While trying to start the Dawnguard DLC quest, when it said to "speak with the leader of the Dawnguard", I tried to complete that objective but every time I try to speak with the Dawnguard leader, he keeps attacking me. Does anyone know how I can stop that from happening?

Comment: Are you a vampire or do you have a bounty?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Isran keeps trying to kill me](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/78533/4797)

Comment: Neither,but that doesn't seem to matter,even though the Dawnguard contacted me

Comment: [This answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/65823/help-im-being-attacked-on-sight-in-dragonsreach/267598#267598) might help... not sure.

Comment: @galacticninja No, that question states that he may have hit Isran, here it doesn't seem he may have hit Isran, it just seems as though Isran is attacking him randomly.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you've fixed it but,what I did when the Dawnguard attacked me-in the middle of the questline-was going to Riften, hitting a guard, putting sword away, get arrested and paid 40 gold for the assault. It worked immediately. Takes a few minutes to try, depending on if you instant travel or walk to Fort Dawnguard.

Comment: This was the one that worked for me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

On assumption of you playing PC I have the answer! Go to console commands (Default Hotkey: ~ Key) click on Isran (while console command is open) and type

> setav aggression 0

or if that fails open Console Commands and type

> resetai

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can try resetting Isran.

Go back to Skyrim, rest for 30 days in-game time, and try again.  This will ensure Isran and everything in his map area are reset.